# Debug Delphi Project Step by step

Tags: delphi

Is there is a way for debugging Delphi program in Rad studio with graphic output?

This means even graphic output(the command that has graphic output like print or shows a message and ...) run step by step.
For example inside loop command, we put print or add an item into list view and if we debug this part we can see the result in the form step by step? each turn of the loop show one print or adding to the list separately(by pressing F7 or F8 for debugging)

I hope I have asked my questions correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Please check out the procedure OutputDebugString

Comment: It is not always that easy, because graphic changes may not become visible on screen immediately, but only at the next `paint` cycle. Sometimes a forced paint cycle (e.g. calling `Repaint` or similar) can help debugging. You need to try something that you are interested in yourself and step through the code with `F7`-Trace into, `F8`- Step over. Then, when you have actual concrete questions with test code please post them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to Debug Delphi applications in the way you describe? I'm afraid it is not.

Why not? Both application logic and UI rendering are done within the main thread. And when you set a breakpoint at certain line of code it stop the execution of the entire thread that the code is being executed from.

Since most if not all of your code is ran from main thread setting a breakpoint halts execution of the entire main thread of the application and thus prevents application windows to be redrawn.

In fact since redrawing of windows content is done during idle time of your application it means that running any long loop inside main thread means that the application UI will be updated only when the loop is finished.

---

You could theoretically force your application to update its UI on each loop cycle by calling `Application.ProcessMessages` before halting the code on a specific breakpoint.

But using of`Application.ProcessMessages` is not recommended as it could lead to scenarios where messages are not handled in expected order and thus could potentially cause you more problems elsewhere.

Also calling `Application.ProcessMesages` could seriously affect your application performance so if you decide to use it only use it for Debugging purposes.

Comment: You do realize that by writing APM three times in a row that it will now magically appear in the OP's code at least the same number of times?

Comment: @KenWhite There is a chance for that yes. But hopefully OP will use this only for debugging purposes as I suggested